# How are implementations of some specific abstract methods from an API internally called?

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio

I'm just curious about it. Currently, I'm trying to write better code, and I found really interesting how easily implementations of the core Android API are made in regard of this good use of object oriented programming.

For example:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {         
      //Our implementation returning some int
   }
}
```

It may seem trivial for you, but for me it's the whole point of object oriented programming. Android API are based on a lot of similar abstract classes that need just some specific implementations to get the work done. But I'm curious about what this "internally called" in the Android documentation refers to.

And to get more specific about my question, how in this "black box", which I'll dig into shortly, the API knows the new instances like "MyService" to access this new implementation.
I'm guessing that it's doing something like:

```
Service service = new MyService();
service.onStartCommand(...);
```

But how it knows about "MyService" instance ?

Comment: Android "knows" about your class types because of the manifest file. You never instantiate your service type, Android does that for you based on your (or others) intents. It never has to know about your instance because you don't have an instance.

Comment: We could also create our own classes that extend specific Android abstract classes, but they will not be called in the manifest file. If i dont have an instance, how it could instantiate it for me ? Sorry, that i dont understand.

Comment: With regards to your specific example of extending the Service class, you must declare services in your manifest file. There's no way around that. What Android abstract class were you thinking of?

Comment: Yes this is true that we need to declare the Service class in our Manifest. But for example, extending AsyncTask and adding specific implementation for the doInBackground abstract method is maybe a more suitable example.

Comment: For AsyncTask, yes you extend and instantiate your own instance. But you then invoke the execute() method on your own instance. In this case, Android didn't have to know about anything. The magic of OO programming called your version of doInBackground(). If you look at the source code for execute(), you'll see where the abstract method doInBackground() is eventually called.